# Matching input alternatives in antlr 4

Tags: java, antlr, antlr4

I am writing a simple parser to translate the query to SQL. I've completed the parser and got the parse tree, but now I need to translate those grammar to SQL using ANTLR 4.

If part of my grammar looks like

```
boolOp : OR|XOR|AND;
```

How will I print it if any matches exists?

Actually, I am trying to print `AND` if my query exists `AND` operator or if my query exists `OR`, then I have to print `OR` operator according to the grammar `boolOp` rule shown above.

**PART OF MY CODE**

```
public void exitBoolOp( Parser.BoolOpContext ctx)
{
    if (ctx.AND() == AND)
    {
        System.out.print(" AND "+"\t");
    }
    else if (ctx.OR() == OR)
    {
        System.out.print(" OR "+"\t");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print(" XOR "+"\t");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious problem I noticed in the code is the generated `AND()`, `OR()`, and `XOR()` methods return a `TerminalNode`, but the `AND`, `OR`, and `XOR` constants are declared as `int`. What you actually want to use is the expression:

```
if (ctx.AND() != null) {
    ...
```

Beyond this, you'll need to include more specific examples of your desired input and output.